# mockk, how to verify a function is called with Map type and interface type

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

The class has a function:

```kotlin
fun theFunc(uri: Uri, theMap: Map<String, String>?, callback: ICallback) {
  ......
}
```

and would like to verify it is called with proper params type

```kotlin
io.mockk.verify { mock.theFunc(ofType(Uri::class), ofType(Map<String,  String>::class), ofType(ICallbak::class)) }
```

the `ofType(Uri::class)` is ok,

the `ofType(Map<String,  String>::class` got error:
[image]

the `ofType(ICallbak::class)` got error:

> ICallback does not have a companion object, thus must be initialized
> here.

How to use the `ofType()` for `Map` and interface?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `mapOf<String,String>::class`

```
io.mockk.verify { mock.theFunc(ofType(Uri::class), ofType(mapOf<String,String>()::class), ofType(ICallbak)) }
```

For interface, you can create mocck object. And put it into ofType.

```
val callbackMock: ICallback = mockk()

io.mockk.verify { mock.theFunc(ofType(Uri::class), ofType(mapOf<String,String>()::class), ofType(callbackMock::class)) }
```

Comment: thanks, what about the interface?

Comment: I updated. Could u try it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that generic parameters are lost at runtime due to [type erasure](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#type-erasure), and for this reason the syntax doesn't allow generic parameters to be specified in that context. You can write `Map::class` but not `Map<String, String>::class` because a `Map<String, String>` is just a `Map` at runtime.

So, you can call it like this:

```
verify { mock.theFunc(ofType(Uri::class), ofType(Map::class), ofType(ICallback::class)) }
```

that will work. However, there is also a version of function `ofType` which takes generic parameters, so you can use this:

```
verify { mock.theFunc(ofType<Uri>(), ofType<Map<String, String>>(), ofType<ICallback>()) }
```

Comment: thanks @klitos! the ofType<Map<String, String>>() passed the compile but the in runtime the map is null so no match is found. How to put in nullable param in the verify?  ofType(Map::class), does not work, but the ofType(ICallback::class) actually worked

Comment: If you are not looking for specific parameter types, i.e. a null is also acceptable, you can just have `verify { mock.theFunc(any(), any(), any()) }`

Comment: I mean, you can use the `or` function to combine matchers, i.e. `verify { mock.theFunc(ofType<Uri>(), or(ofType<Map<String, String>(), isNull()), ofType<ICallback>()) }`, but that would be pointless when you can just use `any()`.